# Почему не загружает картинку на сервер?

Tags: php

Всем привет! Есть вот такой код PHP. Он должен при попытке загрузить картинку на сервер, собственно, загружать картинку на сервер. Проблема в том, что физически картинка там не появляется. В темплейтах путь прописывается, все хорошо. Но самой картинки нет. В чем может быть проблема? Если она не в коде, то где ее искать?

```
$uploaddir = $global_vars['mainpatch'].'/templates/userpic/'; 
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['photo_of_teacher1']['name']); 

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo_of_teacher1']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
{ 
    $image_success = basename($_FILES['photo_of_teacher1']['name']); 
} 
else 
{ 
    $image_suck = "Ошибка загрузки изображения"; 
} 

print_r($_FILES); 

print "</pre>";
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

1) Надо попробовать на простейшем примере, создайте файл index.html с формой:

```
 <form action="server.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="filename" />
        <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

Обратите внимание на следующее:

- метод отправки формы должен быть POST
- В форме должен присутствовать атрибут enctype и значение у него должно быть multipart/form-data
- у инпута с типом file должен быть еще атрибут name, значение которого будет использоваться на сервере.

После этого создайте в этой же папке еще 1 файл server.php, и вставьте в него следующий код:

```
<?php

if(copy($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"],"c:/xampp/htdocs/files/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]))
{
    echo("файл успешно загружен");

} 

else 
{
    echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
}


?>
```

Замените в функции copy, путь на свой, и обратите внимание, что в $_FILES мы передаем имя,  которое  мы указали в index.html в инпуте в атрибуте name в с отправкой файла.
Так же нужно отметить, что в случае если загружать файлы с одинаковым именем в разное время, в каталоге загрузки останется только последний файл, предыдущие он перезатрет. Поэтому как вариант можно менять имя файла при загрузке, заменив:

```
copy($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"],"c:/xampp/htdocs/files/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"])
```

на:

```
copy($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"],"c:/xampp/htdocs/files/".uniqid().$_FILES["filename"]["name"])
```

Попробуйте загрузить файл весом до 1 мб.

Пример полностью рабочий, если он у вас на сервере сработает, значит со средой все в порядке и ищите ошибку в коде, если не сработает тогда нужно искать ошибку в среде.

2) Второе, что нужно проверять это настройки в php.ini:

max_file_uploads - максимальный размер загружаемого файла

post_max_size - максимальный размер данных который можно передавать через post запрос

Если вес картинки превышает эти два параметра, тогда нужно их увеличить.

Comment: Нет, я пробовал разные - от маленького веса до большого. Не помогает((

Comment: Добавил пункт 2, в нем пример, скопируйте его себе, у меня так успешно загружает картинки. И кстати маленькие это сколько по весу?

Comment: От 4 килобайт до 5 мегабайт... Вставил ваш - история точь-в-точь та же! Страницу перезагружает, по клику на картинке указывает ее правильное месторасположение, но самой картинки там нет. Зато правильный путь и ее имя есть. Такой вот парадокс)) Судя по всему, проблема не в этом коде

Comment: добавил пункт 3, проверьте его

Comment: После установки enctype вообще пропало название изображения (т.е. путь есть в адресной строке, а названия самого файла нет). В остальном все так же - форма стандартна, метод POST

Comment: сейчас маленький файл пробовали загружать? попробуйте на файле меньше 1 мб, после того как enctype добавили.

Comment: Да, конечно - и большой и маленький, на выходе одно и то же

Comment: В другом модуле этот код работает корректно

Comment: пардонте, какой еще другой модуль? на этом же сервере, в этом же приложении? После того как enctype  добавили , на сервере код из пункта 2 использовали? Опустошите весь файл и оставьте только код из пункта 2 для чистоты эксперимента. И файл меньше 1 мб.

Comment: Если стереть весь остальной код и оставить этот, то выскакивает надпись Array() и все. Чую я, там какая-то детская ошибка...

Comment: Так обновил свой пост, прописал в него 100% рабочий пример, прочитайте его и выполните 1 в 1 на сервере где у вас не работает загрузка .

Answer (score 0):

Функция для сохранения картинок в папку, путь к которой указан в $path;

```
  public function saveImg() {

    mkdir( $path, 0777 );

    $i = 0;
    $is_saved = false;
    $errors = $_FILES['photos']['error'];

    foreach ( $errors as $key => $error ) {

      if ( $error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {

        $tmp_name = $_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$key];
        move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $path . $i++ . '.jpg' );

        if ( !$is_saved ) $is_saved = true;

      } else {

        if ( $is_saved ) $is_saved = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return $is_saved;
  }
```

Comment: Буду ждать, спасибо) С try-catch никак. Ошибка не здесь, т.к. код выполняется дальше. Сейчас попробую разобраться в других кусках кода...

Comment: ну как, получилось?